# can't ssh from mac to windows (running ssh server on cygwin)

Tags: macos, ssh, cygwin, authentication, sshd

I set up an ssh server on a fresh windows 7 machine using the latest version of cygwin. Disabled the firewall.

I can ssh into it from itself, from a different windows box (using winssh), and from a linux vm. In spite of that, I tried to ssh in from two different macs, and *neither* would let me!

This is the debug output:

```
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 3dbuild [172.18.4.219] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Denise/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Denise/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Denise/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '3dbuild' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Denise/.ssh/known_hosts:43
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Denise/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Denise/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by [ip]
```

It shows the same output, and fails at the same place, whether I have put my public key on the ssh server or not.

Any help would be appreciated-- hopefully someone has run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this issue.  Since MacOS X is really BSD, it has additional security features.   Make sure that your $USER directory is, and your $USER/.ssd is set so that only your user (not group or world) have read permissions to your files.

Comment: I was hopeful, but I changed the permissions on both on the files within .ssh (to u+rw) and on the folders you mentioned (to u+rwx), with no luck.